# How can I stack <div> elements with text content without shifting the text-content?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to stack one or more `<div>` elements on top of another `<div>` element, where both have text content.

I have created a fiddle here illustrating my issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/rd268ucy/1/.
When dragging one of the letters to stack onto another `<div>`, the text content on the underlying `<div>` are shifted downwards, seen with the **c** in this case. [image from jsfiddle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lLMd.png).

How can I stack the elements without moving the text content on the underlying  `<div>`?

Comment: put both divs inside a parent div with `position: relative`, giving both children `position: absolute`

Comment: That helps on not shifting the textContent, however the cells are now shifted a bit relative to the underlying cell? Look at updated jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hc1somud/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added `position: relative` to `.cell` and `position: absolute` with left and top 0 values to `.cell .letterCell`.

Hope this fiddle solves your problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/furkanmutlu/hbgxafeu/